# How to create consecutive non-rainy days ranking list in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, weather

With Jim Dehner's help, I'm able to count the consecutive rainy or non-rainy days by month in the following sheet.

[Rainy Situation Calendar View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNUdc.png)

Here is the result for monthly non-rainy days Amount.

[Monthly Non-Rainy Days Amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IHNo.png)

I have faced a question about how to calculate the consecutive non-rainy days by Year to a ranking list like the below:

[Ideal Ranking List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjs4a.png)

The idea is that I can get a consecutive non-rainy day ranking list with a given date range(Like the Year 2019) to understand the drought situation.

I was able to get a MAX consecutive non-rainy day count, like 16 days for Year 2019.

But like I said I also want to know the other consecutive non-rainy days lower than the MAX.

After this, I would **highlight** the date included in the consecutive non-rainy day range which exceeds specific day count(like more than 10 consecutive non-rainy days, the index from **1-3** in the **Ideal Ranking result**.).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

[Tableau Community question link](https://community.tableau.com/message/1050250#1050250)